# Can anyone walk me through calculating the differential equation...

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I need help solving this equation, i've attempted using numerous methods. But I'm give choices with square roots as an exponent of e, and I haven't been able to match any of them.
 $$ \frac{1}{6x}\frac{dy}{dx}=y\sqrt{3x^2-1} $$
The answers I'm given all have $$e^{\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{(3x^2-1)^3}}$$
and no method I've isolated has managed that answer.

Comment: It's separable.  As differentials we can write $$\frac {dy}y=6x\sqrt {3x^2-1}\,dx$$

Comment: After three similar questions within the last 30 minutes you should know about separation of variables.

Comment: this is, i got it to that. And that's where I got stuck, on integration. I got $$ln(|y|)=3x^2 \frac{(6x^2 - 2)^\frac{2}{3}}{3} + C$$

Comment: Your right hand integral is way off.  You can't integrate term by term like that.  Try a substitution.

Comment: $$ln(|y|)=2 \frac{(3x^2 - 1)^\frac{2}{3}}{3} + C$$ ?

Comment: No, to compute $$\int x \sqrt{x^2-1} dx,$$ substitute $x^2-1=u$ and get 
$$\int x \sqrt{x^2-1}dx = \int \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{u} du = \int \frac{1}{2}u^{1/2}= du=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}u^{3/2}=\frac{1}{3}(x^2-1)^{3/2}$$ I guess you can continue.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to approach this problem is by the method of *separation of variables*. This works as follows.

You try to rewrite the original equation such that on the left hand side, only terms with $y$ and $\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} x}$ are present, while the right hand side is a function of $x$ only. In your case, this yields
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{y} \frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} x} = 6 x \sqrt{3 x^2 -1},
\end{equation}
by multiplying both sides with $\frac{6x}{y}$.

The following step is to integrate both sides with respect to $x$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
 \int^x \frac{1}{y(x)} \frac{\text{d} y(x)}{\text{d} x}\,\text{d} x = \int^x 6 x \sqrt{3x^2-1} \,\text{d} x.
\end{equation}
You can recognise the integrand of the left integral as the $x$-derivative of $\log y(x)$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
 \int^x \frac{1}{y(x)} \frac{\text{d} y(x)}{\text{d} x}\,\text{d} x = \int^x \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} x}\left[\log y(x)\right]\,\text{d} x = \log y(x).
\end{equation}
Therefore, you can express the solution $y(x)$ as
\begin{equation}
 y(x) = \exp \Big[ \int^x 6 x \sqrt{3x^2 -1}\,\text{d} x \Big]
\end{equation}
I leave it to you to calculate this integral.